# Integral of characteristic function in three dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am having difficulty in evaluating the following integral:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) f(y) f(z)\chi_{{(x,x,x): x\in \mathbb{R}}} dx dy dz$.

Could someone please give me some hint or tell me how to approach?

Is it $(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx)^3$ or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^3 dx?$

Any help or hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the notation mean $\chi_{(x,x,x)}(x,y,z) = 1$ if $x = y = z$ and $0$ otherwise? If so, the integral is $0$ for every finite, measurable $f$ because the integrand is supported on a line.

Comment: Indeed, as @AndrewD.Hwang comments, if $\chi$ (for "characteristic function"?) is literally the characteristic function of the diagonal, you'll just get $0$. So, presumably (?), that $\chi$ is a _distribution_ that says "integrate along the diagonal"? Can you clarify?

Comment: Does the answer change if we replace this characteristic function by characteristic function of {x=y} times characteristic of {y=z}?

Comment: No, that's the same thing, $1$ on the diagonal line and $0$ elsewhere. Generally a product of characteristic functions is the characteristic function of the intersection of their supports.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you may interchange integrals it is
$$\int f(x)^3 dx,$$
since the indicator function integrated over $y$ and $z$ is evaluating the function so that
$$\int\int f(y)f(z)\mathbb{1}_{\{x,x,x\}}dydz=f(x)f(x).$$